# jquery slideToggle call once

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide, slidetoggle

That just could be very simple, but it's about 2AM and getting quite sleepy :)

I have short script which "slideToggle" div from being non-displayed.

```
$('#cmnt_add').click(function () { $('.dark_div_add').slideToggle(1100); });
```

Is there a chance to make it workout once, so if non-displayed DIV is opened, clicking same link won't do a thing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.one()`:

```
$('#cmnt_add').one("click", function () { $('.dark_div_add').slideToggle(1100); });
```

From [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element.

Also, if you know it'll be hidden initially, using `.slideDown()` instead of `.slideToggle()` may be a good idea...

Comment: Tnx mate, it really helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

use [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) in stead of [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cmnt_add').click(function () { $('.dark_div_add').slideDown(1100); });
```