# Show/hide menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, show-hide

I have a page with content (on the left) and sidebar (on the right). For screen widths <= 480px the 2 div's are placed one under the other (100% widths). The "Show/Hide" button that becomes visible is meant to toggle the sidebar's visibility when clicked. I use

`$(".sidebar .box").slideToggle(200);`

for this purpose.

See everything together on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqdvj42u/2/).

The problem: if I switch to wide screen and then back to *narrow screen* (width <= 480px) again, clicking the button produces a "back and forth" bug.

Where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery slideToggle call once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799094/jquery-slidetoggle-call-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/jqdvj42u/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("a.expander").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('close');
        $(".sidebar .box").slideToggle(200);
    });
});

function showSidebar() {   
    if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
        // Close sidebar when window width <= 480px
        $(".sidebar .box").removeClass('open');
        // Click expander button to show/hide sidebar

    } else {
        $("a.expander").removeClass('close');
        // Open sidebar when window width > 480px;
        $(".sidebar .box").addClass('open');
    }
}
showSidebar();

$(window).resize(showSidebar);
```

your click shouldnt be called within `showSidebar()` because it'll bind the click event every time that function is called. resize triggers `showSidebar()` multiple times, so the click is bound multiple times. also, you should use jQuery 1.11 as the lowest version since its the most up-to-date version thats stable on IE<9. if you dont mind support on IE<9, use jQuery version 2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is that this code:

```
$("a.expander").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
    $(".sidebar .box").slideToggle(200);
});
```

gets executed *every time* the function `showSidebar` is run, which is every time the window is resized. JQuery's `click` function adds a *new* event handler each time, and executes *all* of them on each window resize.

The solution would be to move the `click` handler registration outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is that your slide function gets called continuously when your window is resized. Rather than have this event occur unchecked, try to control it using an event handler like so:

Use `.one()`:

```
$('#your_element_id').one("click", function () {     
    $('.your_css_style_class').slideToggle(200); 
});
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that if down the line, you desire to display it hidden, you may want to use `.slideDown()` rather than `.slideToggle()` to begin with.

Here is a jQuery reference to the 'one' function: http://api.jquery.com/one

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek its not a duplicate necessarily. that question's answer limits the handler to be executed once, which could be a solution to OP issue, but the better way to handle the issue is to not bind the same handler multiple times in the first place.